Swagger UI Not Working but /v3/api-docs Is Accessible in Spring Boot with Context Path
Problem
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where Swagger UI is not accessible, even though /v3/api-docs works perfectly. My application uses a custom server.servlet.context-path, and I'm unable to resolve the issue despite trying various configurations.
{"type":"about:blank","title":"Not Found","status":404,"detail":"No static resource swagger-ui/index.html.","instance":"/api/swagger-ui/index.html","properties":null}

Details

Spring Boot Version: 3.x
Swagger Dependency:

groovy implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.6.0'
application.yml Configuration:
server:
  port: 3000
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/

springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /v3/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui/index.html
    enable: true
  show-actuator: true

Expected Behavior
Swagger UI should be accessible at:
http://localhost:3000/api/swagger-ui/index.html 
Additional Context
I can't remove the server.servlet.context-path because the application relies on it for other endpoints.
The application uses a custom JacksonConfig and SecurityConfiguration .
1)Dependency Validation:
Verified that springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0 is included and the dependency is correctly downloaded.
2)Explicit Resource Mapping:
Added a custom WebMvcConfigurer to map Swagger UI resources:
@Configuration
public class SwaggerStaticResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/v3/api-docs/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    }
}


3)Spring Security:
Added explicit security rules to allow public access to Swagger endpoints:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    return http.build();
}


4)Dependency Inspection:
Checked the JAR file for springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui and confirmed that META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html exists.

I was facing the same problem. Then resolved the issue by adding the appropriate version of springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.
You need to match the springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui version according to the Spring Boot version of your project.
See the doc about this,
https://springdoc.org/#what-is-the-compatibility-matrix-of-springdoc-openapi-with-spring-boot
